# Struggling to identify the name of a track element that plays alongside the melody

Tags: composition, harmony, melody

I'm deconstructing a track in order to create a track template in Ableton for the kids I teach at a youth centre. A base they can use to start when creating a song.

I'm struggling to label one of the elements of the track. This is probably a trivial question but I don't know this genre at all. I'm deconstructing a track at their request based on what they listen to regularly.

The track is below. The first 8 bars of the track is the melody (the orchestral hits), but on the second 8 bars of the intro another element comes in that sounds like a choir sample:

What is that element of the track called? Would it be classed as harmony? Or another melody? The element comes in at the 7 second mark just after the sample "swifta production". It lasts for 8 bars before the bass comes in, but repeats throughout the track.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a vocal-like chant, or ostinato, layer. It appears to be on one note, so some might say it creates oblique harmony.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the choir samples perform a similar role to the main melody, with the exception that they are less prominent.

So, is it harmony or melody? Both. Melody can imply harmony, particularly when you layer multiple melodies. Bass lines are a really good example of this.

The choir samples also play a rhythmic role. This is not a genre that I'm highly familiar with, but I suspect rhythm is quite important.

So, a term for this type of line. I'm not sure any traditional music theory names are going to help here. Mostly because I suspect those names don't mean anything to your target audience. However, there may be specific terms used within the genre. Why not ask the kids? Or, you could just name it after the instrument that's playing.

If all else fails, you could call it George, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if classical music terms are a lot of use in analysing this type of music, based on repetition of fragments.   Very often when an element is added it is retained and repeated, you could call this adding a layer.  But in this case the vocal sound is just used once, a similar sound next occurs nearly a minute into the song.   It's a bit too long to be called a 'hit'.  Just say it happens, I think.